# remove margins around main layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make a tab widget in android that fills the layout width and is placed directly under the action bar of my activity but the white margins around my tab widget is preventing me from achieving my view, so could anyone please help me to remove these margins (marked by red in the image link below) from around my main relative layout?

[Marked white spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp6cn.jpg)

and following is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.idm.ui.MainActivity" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="-16dp" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="-15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="-17dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:background="#000000">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical|center"
                android:showDividers="none" >
            </TabWidget>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/elvDownloading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </ListView>
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/elvDownloaded"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
                    </ListView>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post you layout XML file, but these are most likely the default activity paddings (defined in `@dimen/activity_vertical_margin` and `@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin`).

Look for `android:padding*` or `android:margin*` values in your layout XML file and set them to 0 or just remove them if not needed.

**Edit after the XML was added:**

Yes, you should remove these lines:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: thanks Nohus, i tried to set custom padding and margins but nothing works,i had already edited my question so please have a look on my code

Comment: Did you try removing these 4 lines?